# c++: Pointers and address

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test_func(char *data,int length)
{
  cout<<"data:"<<data<<endl;
  cout<<"length:"<<length<<endl;

  void *addr=data;
  cout<<"*addr:"<<addr<<endl;
  cout<<"Address of data:"<<&data<<endl;
  cout<<"data again:"<<*(&data)<<endl;
}

int main()
{
  char msg[]="Hello world!";
  test_func(msg,6);

  return 0;
}
```

I was trying some other program where I came accrross `void *addr=data`. so I tried to understand it by writing a separate program for it. And here I am not able to understand what is the value stored in `addr`. I got the output of following program as:

```
data:Hello world!
length:6
*addr:0x794e0553d310
Address of data:0x794e0553d2e8
data again:Hello world!
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an array designator is passed to a function as an argument it is converted to a pointer to its first element.

Function parameters are local variables of the function.

Thus you can imagine function `test_func` along with its call as `test_func(msg,6);`  the following way

```
void test_func( /* char *data,int length */)
{
    char *data = msg;
    int length = 6;

    cout<<"data:"<<data<<endl;
    cout<<"length:"<<length<<endl;

    void *addr=data;
    cout<<"*addr:"<<addr<<endl;
    cout<<"Address of data:"<<&data<<endl;
    cout<<"data again:"<<*(&data)<<endl;
}
```

In this case expression `&data` used in statement

```
cout<<"Address of data:"<<&data<<endl;
```

is the address of function local variable `data`
Accotding to the output

```
Address of data:0x794e0553d2e8
```

variable `data` is placed at address `0x794e0553d2e8` inside the function. The variable itself contains the address of the first character of array `msg` because it was assigned such a way when the function was called.:)

```
    char *data = msg;
```

So the address of the variable `data` and the value stored in the variable differ.

As for this expression

```
*(&data)
```

then it is equivalent to expression

```
data
```

Thus statement

```
cout<<"data again:"<<*(&data)<<endl;
```

outputs the string the address of the first character of which is stored in pointer `data`.

`operator <<` is overloaded for pointers of type `char *` It considers the object pointed to by such a pointer as a string and outputs it accordingly. Take into account that `&data` has type `char **`. It is not the same as `char *`. So for pointers of type `char **` (and of other types) there is used overloaded `operator <<` that interpretates such pointers as `const void *` and simply outputs the corresponding value.

Answer (score 2):

operator `<<` is overloaded for `cout`, so if you pass a `char*` it prints the content (even though `char*` is a pointer).

However, if you pass a void pointer (`addr` in your example) it will print the address itself. So `addr` is the address of the first element of the message.

On the other hand, `&data` is a pointer to a pointer, so `cout` prints the address of `data` (with `data` being a pointer to your message).

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a pointer to the first `char` of a string, which is how strings are implemented in C. When you assign it to `addr`, you are just getting rid of the static type of `data`.

The reason you get different results when you output `addr` and `data` is that `std::cout` treats `char*` as a special case: it is output as a string rather than having its pointer value printed. `void*` doesn't share this, so you just see the address.

Answer (score 0):

```
void *addr=data"
```

When you write above statement, `addr` is a pointer of type `void*`  and which has an address in memory.  And it will be different from the address of the variable `data` of type `char*`. So when you print  as follows

```
cout<<"*addr:"<<addr<<endl;
cout<<"Address of data:"<<&data<<endl;
```

Each statement will print corresponding address of those variables.

*addr=data;

The above statement will not change the address of variable `addr` instead it will redirect  the address location of `addr` to the address location of `data`.